# VBA - Change Cell based on a list and then save a new workbook based on that cell / list

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook already with a macro that does several things based on a cell value:

When i change a cell value (its a store name) the code will filter several sheets with, just to show the store of that specific cell, then hides several sheets. 
Just showing 2 specific sheets.
And in the end of the code i save a new workbook with the name of that store.

My question is:

Is it possible to change my code (shown below), so i dont have to write manually the name of the store, ie, i want that the macro sees a list of stores, then change the cell with each store, do all the tasks i want, and then writes a new workbook with that store name, and so on, until the end of the list store?

Thank you so much

(PS: im new in vba, so my code probably is a little rough around the edges)

```
Sub Nova_loja()

   Dim sht As Worksheet
   Dim Fname As String
   Dim Cell As Range, cRange As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = False

    'copy past in values

    With Range("K44:L66")
        .Cells.Copy
        .Cells.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End With

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

  'filter and delete

    Sheets("BD Geral").Select
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table2").Range.AutoFilter Field:=52, Criteria1:="<>" & Worksheets("Tabela - Média Mensal").Range("B2").value, Operator:=xlFilterValues

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table2").DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table2").AutoFilter.ShowAllData

    'filter and delete

    Sheets("BD BONUS_MALUS").Select
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table35").Range.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="<>" & Worksheets("Tabela - Média Mensal").Range("B1").value, Operator:=xlFilterValues

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table35").DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True


    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table35").AutoFilter.ShowAllData


    'filter and delete

    Sheets("BD NPS").Select
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table3").Range.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="<>" & Worksheets("Tabela - Média Mensal").Range("B1").value, Operator:=xlFilterValues

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table3").DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table3").AutoFilter.ShowAllData


    Sheets("BD Dept").Select
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table4").Range.AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:="<>" & Worksheets("Tabela - Média Mensal").Range("B1").value, Operator:=xlFilterValues

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table4").DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table4").AutoFilter.ShowAllData




    'refresh pivots

    ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll


    'hide sheets

    For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If sht.Name <> "Dashboard" And sht.Name <> "Tabela - Média Mensal" Then
    sht.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
    End If
    Next sht



    'protect sheets

    For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
       sht.Protect Password:="fnacrh", AllowSorting:=True, AllowFiltering:=True, AllowUsingPivotTables:=True
    Next



    'leave active main worksheet

    Sheets("Dashboard").Select



    'save as with new name

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False





    Fname = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "02.VIM_REPORT MENSAL - " & Worksheets("aux").Range("V2") & " - " & Worksheets("aux").Range("V3") & ".xlsx"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Fname, FileFormat:=xlWorkbookDefault







    Application.DisplayAlerts = True


    Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True




End Sub
```

Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The next code would do what I understood you need.
Copy the next code in a module of another workbook, different from the one to be processed, and run `AutomaticallySelectStore` procedure. An InputBox will appear asking to select the number from the right side of the workbook name to be processed.

```
   Sub AutomaticallySelectStore()
            Dim w As Workbook, Wb As Workbook, sh As Worksheet, store As Variant, Arr As Variant, Ans As String
            Dim i As Long, strWorkb As String, strWbName As String, strWbPath As String, nrStores As Long

            strWorkb = "Please write the number of the workbook needed to be processed:" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf

            For Each Wb In Workbooks
                i = i + 1
                strWorkb = strWorkb & Wb.name & " - " & i & vbCrLf
            Next
            strWorkb = left(strWorkb, Len(strWorkb) - 1)
            Ans = InputBox(strWorkb, "Necessary workbook selection", 1)
              If Ans = "" Then MsgBox "You did not select anything...", vbInformation, "No workbook selected": Exit Sub
              If Not IsNumeric(Ans) Then
                MsgBox "You must write the number from the right side of the needed workbook name!", vbInformation, _
                        "Wrong choice...": Exit Sub
              ElseIf Ans > Workbooks.Count Then
                MsgBox "You must write a number less or equal with " & Workbooks.Count, vbInformation, _
                        "Wrong chosen number": Exit Sub
              End If

            Set w = Workbooks(CLng(Ans))

             On Error Resume Next
               Set sh = w.Worksheets("aux")
             If Err.Number <> 0 Then
                Err.Clear: On Error GoTo 0
                MsgBox "The chosen workbook looks to be wrong..." & vbCrLf & _
                       " Worksheet ""Tabela - Média Mensal"" is missing.", vbInformation, _
                       "Wrong workbook or necessary worksheet missing": Exit Sub
             End If
             On Error GoTo 0

             strWbName = w.FullName
             nrStores = sh.Range("AF2").End(xlDown).Row
             Arr = sh.Range("AF2:AF" & nrStores)
             w.Activate
             i = 0
             Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
              For Each store In Arr
                i = i + 1
                Nova_loja strWbName, store, i, nrStores - 1
              Next
             Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
             Application.StatusBar = "Ready..."
        End Sub

    Sub Nova_loja(strWbName As String, store As Variant, No As Long, NrPag As Long)

       Dim sht As Worksheet, fName As String, Cell As Range, cRange As Range
       Dim w As Workbook, Wb As Workbook, boolFound As Boolean, shortName As String
       Dim Arr As Variant, shAr As Worksheet, shortWbName As String

       shortWbName = Right(strWbName, Len(strWbName) - InStrRev(strWbName, "\"))
       For Each Wb In Workbooks
            If Wb.FullName = strWbName Then
                Set w = Wb: boolFound = True: Exit For
            End If
       Next
       If Not boolFound Then
            Set w = Workbooks.Open(strWbName)
       End If

        Application.ScreenUpdating = False

        Application.StatusBar = "Working on " & store & " store (" & No & " of " & NrPag & ")..."
        Application.CalculateBeforeSave = True


        Set shAr = Workbooks(shortWbName).Worksheets("aux")
        Arr = shAr.Range("K44:L66")
        shAr.Range("K44:L66") = Arr


        Sheets("Tabela - Média Mensal").Range("B2").Value = store

        Sheets("BD Geral").ListObjects("Table2").Range.AutoFilter field:=52, Criteria1:="<>" & store, _
                                                                                    Operator:=xlFilterValues

        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
          Sheets("BD Geral").ListObjects("Table2").DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete
          Sheets("BD Geral").ListObjects("Table2").AutoFilter.ShowAllData 'it returns an error if no filter is applied
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True

        'filter and delete
        Sheets("BD BONUS_MALUS").ListObjects("Table35").Range.AutoFilter field:=3, Criteria1:="<>" & Worksheets("Tabela - Média Mensal").Range("B1").Value, Operator:=xlFilterValues

        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
         Sheets("BD BONUS_MALUS").ListObjects("Table35").DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True

        Sheets("BD BONUS_MALUS").ListObjects("Table35").AutoFilter.ShowAllData

        'filter and delete
        Sheets("BD NPS").ListObjects("Table3").Range.AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:="<>" & Worksheets("Tabela - Média Mensal").Range("B1").Value, Operator:=xlFilterValues

        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
         Sheets("BD NPS").ListObjects("Table3").DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True

        Sheets("BD NPS").ListObjects("Table3").AutoFilter.ShowAllData

        'This sheet does not contain any "Table"...
        Sheets("BD Dept").ListObjects("Table4").Range.AutoFilter field:=8, Criteria1:="<>" & Worksheets("Tabela - Média Mensal").Range("B1").Value, Operator:=xlFilterValues

        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
         Sheets("BD Dept").ListObjects("Table4").DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True

        Sheets("BD Dept").ListObjects("Table4").AutoFilter.ShowAllData

        'hide sheets
        For Each sht In w.Worksheets
            If sht.name <> "Dashboard" And sht.name <> "Tabela - Média Mensal" Then
                sht.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
            End If
        Next sht

        'protect sheets
        For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
           sht.Protect Password:="fnacrh", AllowSorting:=True, AllowFiltering:=True, AllowUsingPivotTables:=True
        Next

        'leave active main worksheet
        Sheets("Dashboard").Select

        w.RefreshAll

        shortName = "02.VIM_REPORT MENSAL - " & store & " - " & Worksheets("aux").Range("V3") & ".xlsx"
        fName = w.Path & "\" & shortName
         Application.DisplayAlerts = False
          ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=fName, FileFormat:=xlWorkbookDefault
          Workbooks(shortName).Close , False
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True

        Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End Sub
```

Please, test it and confirm if it works as expected.
If not, mention what wrong happens.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203354/discussion-on-answer-by-faneduru-vba-change-cell-based-on-a-list-and-then-save).

Answer (score 0):

Would that 'list of stores' be another excel workbook/sheet?
Do we have to deduce where the 'store' in discussion exists in your workbook?
Isn't it better you to describe where the change must be done?

Of course, this is not an answer but I do not know how else I can clarify the issue...

Comment: The lists of stores would be in the sheet "aux" starting on the column "AF". On the same workbook. The change its going to be on the cell  "B2" on the sheet "Tabela - Média Mensal"

Comment: Can you better explain the scenario you need to be implemented? Shell we understand that in column "AF:AF" there will be strings meaning what you say 'stores'? Starting from the "AF2" and going down. For each such a 'Store' do you need to run the above code replacing 'Worksheets("Tabela - Média Mensal").Range("B2").value' with the string found in each AF column cell?

Comment: And where do you need to manually write `a value'...? In "Worksheets("Tabela - Média Mensal").Range("B2")" cell?

Comment: At this moment im writing, manually, around 60 stores, and running the macro where it hides the sheets i want to hide, delete the data from other stores, and save a new workbook with this changes... And this is time consuming, so wanted to stop writing manually the store name. Yes the column is on AF:AF, and its starting at "AF1". Yes, for each store i need to run the code, so the data its delete from other stores and then hides the data sheets, only showing tables and the charts

Comment: I write the name of the store in the cell you mention:   "Worksheets("Tabela - Média Mensal").Range("B2")"

Comment: OK. It is not so complicate. In some minutes  I will post the code. Basically, the existing code must be modified in order to accept a parameter (store) which will replace your existing range. Then, another sub introducing the specified column cells values in an array and then iterate for each of them in order to call the existing modified one...

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub AutomaticallySelectStore()
    Dim W As Workbook, Sh As Worksheet, store As Variant, Arr As Variant
    Set W = ActiveWorkbook
     Set Sh = W.Worksheets("Tabela - Média Mensal")
     Arr = Sh.Range("AF2:AF" & Sh.Range("AF2").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row)
     For Each store In Arr
        Nova_loja store
     Next
End Sub

Sub Nova_loja(store As Variant)

   Dim sht As Worksheet, Fname As String, Cell As Range, cRange As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = False

    With Range("K44:L66")
        .Cells.Copy
        .Cells.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End With

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

  'filter and delete

    Sheets("BD Geral").Select
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table2").Range.AutoFilter Field:=52, Criteria1:="<>" & store, Operator:=xlFilterValues

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table2").DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table2").AutoFilter.ShowAllData

    'filter and delete

    Sheets("BD BONUS_MALUS").Select
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table35").Range.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="<>" & Worksheets("Tabela - Média Mensal").Range("B1").Value, Operator:=xlFilterValues

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table35").DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table35").AutoFilter.ShowAllData

    'filter and delete

    Sheets("BD NPS").Select
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table3").Range.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="<>" & Worksheets("Tabela - Média Mensal").Range("B1").Value, Operator:=xlFilterValues

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table3").DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table3").AutoFilter.ShowAllData

    Sheets("BD Dept").Select
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table4").Range.AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:="<>" & Worksheets("Tabela - Média Mensal").Range("B1").Value, Operator:=xlFilterValues

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table4").DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table4").AutoFilter.ShowAllData

    'refresh pivots

    ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll

    'hide sheets

    For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If sht.Name <> "Dashboard" And sht.Name <> "Tabela - Média Mensal" Then
    sht.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
    End If
    Next sht

    'protect sheets

    For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
       sht.Protect Password:="fnacrh", AllowSorting:=True, AllowFiltering:=True, AllowUsingPivotTables:=True
    Next

    'leave active main worksheet

    Sheets("Dashboard").Select

    'save as with new name

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Fname = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "02.VIM_REPORT MENSAL - " & Worksheets("aux").Range("V2") & " - " & Worksheets("aux").Range("V3") & ".xlsx"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Fname, FileFormat:=xlWorkbookDefault

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

So, you must run `'AutomaticallySelectStore'` procedure and wait...
I do not have such a file in order to test it, so, it is a code based only on VBA logic and my understanding about your situation.
Depending on how big are your workbooks it may load your system RAM and CPU, working continuously. I am waiting for some feedback.
The initial code can also be optimized a little, but let us see how it works now.

Comment: Im finishing something urgent, but after i finish it i will test it and give feedback.

Comment: Just one question at this moment when i run the macro in the the workbook is saved as and the "template" workbook is closed. This will still happen, and if it do it will still run the macro to all the stores? (thank you so much for the help :))

Comment: I must confess I did not look too much to the code itself... And your question is a good one.  I am afraid it will not work in this circumstances. But it must be a work around. The code must be run from a different workbook, remaining open for all the process. The code will not refer to the AcctiveDocument. You will receive a InputBox/MsgBox giving you the possibility to choose the document from the range of the opened ones. Then, after processing of each store the workbook will be saved with each appropriate name and the master (let as say) workbook will be opened again and reprocessed.

Comment: But now I must live the office. I will look at it after some hours and I will give you a sign here, with a new code...

Comment: @Vanessa Goncalves: Did you receive the addin and using instructions? I can see that our discussion has been moved to chat. I sent you a message there but no answer. So, did you see my comment with the link to the files? If not, this is the link: [addin download](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/243fd0260687fcb408fdbf096e3a7fe520191129194240/dc2e5fb51d404af6ad074464a2000cf620191129194241/33668d?utm_campaign=WT_email_tracking&utm_content=general&utm_medium=download_button&utm_source=notify_recipient_email).

Comment: @Vanessa Goncalves: In order to see the chat room where our conversation has been moved, you must go here [our chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203354/discussion-on-answer-by-faneduru-vba-change-cell-based-on-a-list-and-then-save). When you want to find a chat room and no clue about its site address you can go here [chat site](chat.stackoverflow.com) and look for the discussion. It will be something like this: "Discussion between..." followed by something like this "Importent from a comment discussion on...". I never used the stackoverflow chat until now, neither...